# how to insert to a table when my primary key is already known and in the table sql

Tags: sql

I have a table called server preference it has a primary key called guild_id.
I have to other column called mod_role_id and channel.id (both int)
I want to insert into the correct row where there matching guild id (I know the guild id) 
how do I do it?
please don’t answer with go read this unless its a clear answer
thank you and have a great day!

Comment: This is a little unclear. Are you saying you already have a record in the table with a specific primary id and you want to insert another one with the same id? If so, you can't have two records with the same primary id. Or are you wanting to replace the existing record that has a specific guild id with a new one? Note that in SQL parlance, the word "insert" really means to add it to the table (not replace) whereas "update" means you are changing an existing record. So perhaps your terminology is what makes it confusing.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are describing `update`:

```
update server_preference
    set mod_role_id = :mod_role_id,
        channel_id = :channel_id
    where guild_id = :guild_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

INSERT INTO server_prefernce (guild_id,mod_role_id,channel_id) VALUES (*,*,*)